# Find all files recursively in folder with *.php extension and save it to Word file

Tags: php, file, ms-word, export

I need to make documentation of my project which should consist of all *.php project files.

It must be exported to Word (.*docx) file or PDF.

In Microsoft Word (*.docx) file there should be all *.php files and each file listed should have it's name, path and content.

I am using Sublime Text for files manipulation, but I think it's not capable of this.

Can somebody recommend me any software/script that will be capable of this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You could write a PHP script capable of doing this.

Comment: With php you can use this solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function

Answer (score 0):

In *nix you can simply `cd your_project_dir; find . -name '*.php'`

Comment: Or you could use PHP's `glob()` or `GlobIterator` to find files matching a regex pattern.