# Get filename from each folder (like nested) using PHP

Tags: php, file, directory

My directory Structure is like

```
car_brands/AAA/alto.php
car_brands/BBB/figo.php
car_brands/CCC/beat.php
```

PHP Code

```
     <?php   
             $dir = "Car_Brands";  
             $dh  = opendir($dir);  
             while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh))) 
             {     
              $files[] = $filename;  
              }  
              natcasesort($files); 
               foreach ($files as $file) 
                {
                if($file!='.' && $file!='..')   
                {  
                 echo $file;
                } 
               }    
?>
```

Like I want

```
<a href="Car_Brands/<?php echo $file; ?>/"here i want filename of particular folder"" class="btn btn-red" style="width:180px;height:50px;"><br/><?php echo $file; ?><br/></a>
```

By This code I can get folders under car_brands.like AAA,BBB,CCC but how can get the php filename under each folder in single foreach loop is there any easy way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)

Comment: If I use tht its showing error like : Call to undefined function getDirContents()

Comment: In that question they get all path and filenames but I want foldername alone in one variable array and filename inside specific folder in seperate variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get the list of all files in a given directory.

So, your code be changed like this:

```
         $dir = "Car_Brands";  
         $dh  = opendir($dir);  
         while (false !== ($subdir = readdir($dh))) 
         {   
             $fileList = scandir($dir.'/'.$subdir);
             $files[] = $fileList[2];  
         }  
         natcasesort($files); 
         foreach ($files as $file) 
         {
            if($file!='.' && $file!='..')   
            {  
                 echo $file;
            } 
         }
```

scandir() returns an array that contains the list of all the files in the given directory. If you are in linux server and you are sure each of your directory has one file only, you should get your file name from the 3rd index of the Array, which is `$fileList[2]` in our case. It is the 3rd index cause if you do a var dump of the array that scandir() returns you will see something like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => .
    [1] => ..
    [2] => alto.php
)
```

I would recommend you to do a `print_r($fileList)` within your loop, that will give you a better idea on what index to look at.

**Update**

You can also use [glob](http://www.php.net/glob). In that case your code will look like the below:

```
         $dir = "Car_Brands";
         $dh  = opendir($dir);
         while (false !== ($dirname = readdir($dh)))
         {
             if ($dirname == '..' || $dirname == '.') {
                 continue;
             }
             $subdir = $dir.'/'.$dirname.'/';
             $ext = '*.php';
             $fileList = glob($subdir.$ext);
             if (!empty($fileList)) {
                 $files[] = $fileList[0];
                 // The above line will return the whole path. (eg. car_brands/AAA/alto.php)
                 // if you want the file name only (eg. alto.php) use the below line instead
                 // $files[] = str_replace($subdir, '', $fileList[0]);
             }
         }
         natcasesort($files);
         foreach ($files as $file)
         {
             echo $file;
         }
```

Comment: <a href="Car_Brands/<?php echo $file; ?>/<?php echo strtolower($file)?>.php" class="btn btn-red" style="width:180px;height:50px;"><br/><?php echo $file; ?><br/></a>  I want path like this here it echo altoalto_new.php .How can i split alto in one variable and alto_new.php in another variable

Comment: Array ( [0] => . [1] => .. [2] => images [3] => vista.php ) its just return this only

Comment: Very simple user.If I give one folder like('alto') I just want in return as alto_new.php alone wht can i do

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 
               foreach ($files as $file) 
                {
                if($file!='.' && $file!='..')   
                {
                $dir_path="Car_Brands/".$file."/";  
  $files_names = implode("",preg_grep('~\.(php)$~', scandir($dir_path)));
                    ?>        
               <div class="col-md-2"><br/>      
               <a href="Car_Brands/<?php echo $file; ?>/<?php 
          echo $files_names; ?>" class="btn btn-red" style="width:180px;height:50px;"><br/><?php echo $file; ?><br/></a>      </div>
               <?php 
               } 
               }    
                ?>
```

This is how I tried now its working thanks for everyone who helped me with new ideas