# How to get the number of files in the folder recursive in php

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I have folder structure like below in my web application.

[image]

How can I get the number of files in each folder recursively using php.
I'm working with Codeignaiter.
I haven't any idea for how to do this task.

> I can't use **scandir** function because there are no physical
>   directory in path.Only files and folders save in database.

This is my database

[image]

Please any help needed. 
Thank you.

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: recursive directory iterator or some other recursive function?

Comment: No I haven't any idea how to start it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function

Comment: @Tiger - No it's not duplicate I can't use `scandir` function because there is no any path only saving folders and files in database.

Comment: @MenakaKariyawasam might be [The RecursiveDirectoryIterator class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) can help you see my answer.

Comment: @MenakaKariyawasam, please, see my answer. I guess it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function by passing the path as a parameter in it:

```
function getFileCount($path) {
        $size = 0;
        $ignore = array('.','..','cgi-bin','.DS_Store');
        $files = scandir($path);
        foreach($files as $t) {
            if(in_array($t, $ignore)) continue;
            if (is_dir(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t)) {
                $size += getFileCount(rtrim($path, '/') . '/' . $t);
            } else {
                $size++;
            }   
        }
        return $size;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort.but I can't use this because its not physical directory.and I can't use `scandir` function because there is no any directory path.only save in database.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get, say, all the `*.php` files in your project folder, recursively, you could use the following: [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

```
<?php

$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('path/to/project/');
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+\.php$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

?>
```

`$Regex` will contain a single index array for each PHP file.

Comment: But the problem is I haven't any `path` only files and folders saving in database and display database data.

Comment: @MenakaKariyawasam can you show you database entry ?

Comment: I added my database structure.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) to get kind of [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) but for your virtual filesystem:

```
class RecursiveVirtualDirectoryIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    private $files;

    public function __construct($parentId, $array = [], $flags = 0)
    {
        $this->files = $array;

        parent::__construct(
            $this->getFilesByParentId($parentId),
            $flags
        );
    }

    private $children;
    public function hasChildren()
    {
        $file = $this->current();

        if ($file['is_file']) {
            return false;
        }

        $this->children = $this->getFilesByParentId($file['id']);

        return !empty($this->children);
    }

    private function getFilesByParentId($id)
    {
        return array_filter($this->files, function ($file) use ($id) {
            return $file['parent_id'] === $id;
        });
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        $file = $this->current();
        return new static(
            $file['id'],
            $this->children,
            $this->getFlags()
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over your array returned from databases using [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and count files for, say, topmost folders:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveVirtualDirectoryIterator(0, $files),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

$currentDirectoryName = null;
$filesCount = [];
foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($iterator->getDepth() === 0 && !$file['is_file']) {
        $currentDirectoryName = $file['name'];
        $filesCount[$currentDirectoryName] = 0;
        continue;
    }

    $filesCount[$currentDirectoryName] += 1; 
}
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a9af1f4c1fddbcfc8b860fdbc6abac56d4c79f2).

While [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) is poorly documented, it contains many useful things that save you from reinventing the wheel over and over again.