# How to create subdirectory arrays with glob

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I have the following directory structure:

```
MainFolder
    Folder1
        Folder1-1
             Folder1-1-1  
             Folder1-1-2
             Folder1-1-3    
        Folder1-2
             Folder1-2-1  
             Folder1-2-2
             Folder1-2-3  
    Folder2
        Folder2-1
             Folder2-1-1  
             Folder2-1-2
             Folder2-1-3  
        Folder2-2
             Folder2-2-1  
             Folder2-2-2
             Folder2-2-3
```

I'm trying to create 3 arrays

1 - array of all subfolders of MainFolder (Folder1, Folder2..etc)

2 - array of subfolders inside of Folder1, Folder2, etc (e.g:Folder1-1...folder2-1...)

3 - array of subfolders inside Folder1-1..., Folder1-2..., etc

this way I can only filter the subdirectories of the current directory:

```
//path to directory to scan
$directory = "MainFolder/";

//get all files in specified directory
$files = glob($directory . "*");

//print each file name
foreach($files as $file)
{
 //check to see if the file is a folder/directory
 if(is_dir($file))
 {
  echo $file;
 }
}
```

but how do I, for glob to filter the current directory and automatically group into array as I showed in the example?

I already saw that `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` exists but I did not understand how to put it in different arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thanks, I already saw this question, but I could not create the separate arrays

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php there's a comment by sharshun that may interest you.

Comment: @Jhecht thanks, but in that case it does a fully sequential array of directories and subdirectories, it does not separate the directories into different arrays, if there is another array is a sequential file found in folders and subfolders

Comment: Do you need just 3 arrays, or do you want to keep going as far as possible?

Comment: @Barmar just 3 arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fixed low depth, so you don't really need recursive imho.

You can use wildcard * to mark different levels and **GLOB_ONLYDIR** to retrieve folders only :

```
$level1 = glob('MainFolder/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$level2 = glob('MainFolder/*/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$level3 = glob('MainFolder/*/*/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

If you want to store the last folder instead of full path you can use **array_map()** and **basename()** :

```
$level1 = array_map('basename', glob('MainFolder/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR));
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into a function so you can call it for each directory at a particular level.

```
function all_subdirectories($directory) {
    $files = glob("$directory/*");
    return array_filter($files, 'is_dir');
}
```

Here's code that will create a 2-dimensional array with every level.

```
$all_levels = array();
$dirs = array("MainFolder");
while (!empty($dirs)) {
    $next_level = array();
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        $next_level += all_subdirectories($dir);
    }
    if (!empty($next_level)) {
        $all_levels[] = array_map('basename', $next_level);
    }
    $dirs = $next_level;
}

print_r($all_levels);
```

For just 3 levels it's simpler:

```
$level1 = all_subdirectories("MainFolder");
$level2 = all_subdirectories("MainFolder/*");
$level3 = all_subdirectories("MainFolder/*/*");
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar,  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'in'`... I've always used `as` in foreach the first time I see using `in`

Comment: Sorry, had Python on the brain. A couple of days ago I did the opposite in a Python answer.

Comment: :)  now it's showing: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'` in line  `if (!empty($next_level) {`

Comment: Missing parenthesis, obviously.

Comment: it was just one `)` missing... now appears to have some error in the function:  `Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in` referring to part: `return array_filter('is_dir', $files);` and other error `Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in` referring to part: `$next_level += all_subdirectories($dir);`

Comment: Had the arguments to `array_filter` backwards.

Comment: now it is no error, but the array is empty: `print_r($dirs);` result: `Array ( )`

Comment: The final result is in `$all_levels`

Comment: yeah i've already been trying `print_r($all_levels);`  this too returning empty

Comment: I just tested my code and it works. Are you sure you put the correct folder name in the initial `$dirs`?

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you very much, had a `/` more to put the path of the directory