# get folders and files like in a file explorer

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm confused about all the file system functions in php (glob, scandir, opendir...)
I simply want a list of folders and files - like in a file explorer
something like this:

```
$path = 'home';
$arr = content of $path;
foreach($arr as $el){
if($el is a folder){echo "<div class='folder'>$el</div>";}
elseif($el is a file){echo "<div class='file'>$el</div>";}
}
```

Any help?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function/35315903) might help you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach :

```
$path = 'home'; // setting path

# Find pathnames matching a pattern 
# pattern : "home/*"
# will match : home/dir1, home/file.jpg, etc.
# and it will return an array
$arr = glob($path."/*");
foreach($arr as $el){
if ( is_dir($el) ) {
        echo "<div class='folder'>" . basename($el) . "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='file'>" . basename($el) . "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `home/dir1`, `home/file.jpg` is not like in a file explorer - but - `dir1`, `file.jpg`...

Comment: yeah, but if you want to just print the filename, just apply `basename` function to `$el`

Comment: almost solved. how to get `file` without `jpg` or any extension ?

Comment: you can do that with `pathinfo` function, `pathinfo($el, PATHINFO_FILENAME)`