# Remove files recursively with php - specific pattern only - PHP

Tags: php, unlink

Searched through this site and tried some suggestions but no luck so far.

I have a bunch of files containing this string in the filename: " 2"
for example: test 2.php or imagename 2.jpg

I want to remove all files that contain the " 2" string from root folder (/httpsdocs) **and all subfolders.**

Tried this:

```html
foreach (glob("* 2.*") as $filename) {
    unlink($filename);
```

and this works but obviously only in root folder.

How can I get this to work recursively?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that ?

```
public function removeFilesOnDirectory($path)
{

    $files = glob($path . '/*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if(is_dir($file)) {
            $this->removeDirectory($file);
        } else {
            if (str_contains($file, '2' /* Your constraint */)) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Call this->removeDirectory(/* your path */);

Works for me, just testing it :)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I would use a built-in [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) to make it as simple as possible.

```php
<?php

$directoryIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/httpsdocs");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directoryIterator) as $file) {
    if(strpos($file->getFilename(), ' 2.')) {
        // if filename has specified substring, remove the file
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

If you use PHP8 you can take advantage of the new [str_containt()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) function instead of strpos().

Comment: Are you sure it is OK to manipulating the content of the directory while iterating over it? If so, where is this documented?