# Have PHP Video Gallery include subfolders and display the videos?

Tags: php

I'm using a php video gallery from [codeboxx](https://code-boxx.com/simple-php-video-gallery/) in an attempt to see all the videos my security camera is uploading to my hosting. My camera makes many subfolders for dates and hours which I can't keep anticipating. What I've been trying to get is for this script to include subfolders:

```
  <body>
    <div id="vid-gallery"><?php
      // (A) GET ALL VIDEO FILES FROM THE GALLERY FOLDER
      $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "gallery" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
      $videos = glob($dir . "*.{webm,mp4,ogg}", GLOB_BRACE);

      // (B) OUTPUT ALL VIDEOS
      if (count($videos) > 0) { foreach ($videos as $vid) {
        printf("<video src='gallery/%s'></video>", rawurlencode(basename($vid)));
      }}
    ?></div>
  </body>
```

I think I can get the first part to work in scanning 4 subfolders deep by me doing this:

```
      $dir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "{gallery,gallery/**,gallery/**/**,gallery/**/**/**,gallery/**/**/**/**}" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Now I think this line is giving me a problem as I can't seem to get this src get videos in the subdirectories and wildcards don't seem to work:

```
  printf("<video src='gallery/%s'></video>", rawurlencode(basename($vid)));
```

I've tried to look up how to do it and I've seen array/echo/recursive functions, but I don't know how to implement anything. I appreciate any help.

Comment: A combo of `recursiveDirectoryIterator` and recurseiveIterator` will do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all the files and folders in a Directory with PHP recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783862/list-all-the-files-and-folders-in-a-directory-with-php-recursive-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but along the right lines - a combination of [recursiveIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php) & [recursiveDirectoryIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) ought to be enough to list all the files - when combined further with `pathinfo` to find the file extension you can do away with the `glob` or `preg_match`

```
$dir=sprintf('%s/gallery',__DIR__);
$exts=array('webm','ogg','mp4');

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
if( is_object( $files ) ){
    foreach( $files as $name => $file ){
        if( !$file->isDir() && !in_array( $file->getFileName(), array('.','..') ) ){
            
            if( in_array( pathinfo( $file->getFileName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ),$exts ) ){
                echo $file->getFileName() . '<br />';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An update that loads the videos as per the request

```
$dir=sprintf('%s/gallery', __DIR__ );
$exts=array('webm','ogg','mp4');

$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );
if( is_object( $files ) ){
    foreach( $files as $name => $file ){
        if( !$file->isDir() && !in_array( $file->getFileName(), array( '.', '..' ) ) ){
            
            if( in_array( pathinfo( $file->getFileName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION ),$exts ) ){
                /*
                    For my test the script is running within an `aliased` folder
                    outside of the directory root. The gallery folder and it's
                    sub-folders are within this alised directory.
                    
                    Roughly the structure is:
                    
                    c:\wwwroot\sites\myWebsite ~ this is the directory root
                    
                    The aliased folder - as `demo`:
                    c:\wwwroot\content\
                    
                    The working directory:
                    c:\wwwroot\content\stack 
                    
                    with the gallery
                    c:\wwwroot\content\stack\gallery etc
                    
                    So - I needed to remove the absolute portion of the returned filepaths
                       c:\wwwroot\content
                */
                $rel_filepath=str_replace( 
                    array( realpath( getcwd() ), '\\' ),
                    array( '', '/' ),
                    $file->getPathName()
                );
                
                
                $rel_filepath=ltrim( $rel_filepath, '/' );
                
                
                printf( '<h5>%1$s</h5><video src="%1$s" controls></video>', $rel_filepath );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which resulted in the following display:

[image: Example output]

Comment: This looks very good, but I am sub par because I have tried to get video to output and I can't seem to get the gallery working. What you did successfully accessed subfolders for sure and I have a page of all the files being displayed. How do I combine what you did with getting each filename in <video src=''></video>

Comment: You need to remove a portion of the filepath as they will be absolute filepaths rather than relative. Without seeing more of the returned strings & without knowing your server setup ( directory root etc ) it is tough to say what you need to remove